# NEED HELP - Create Trigger to update column

Tags: sql, sql-update, postgresql-9.4, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

Trying to create trigger function to update column in point layer to update column with ID from another point. 
First layer - it's equipment installed on pole(second layer). Just want to fill information about pole when adding new equipment.

Tried this code: (I'm using similar for history backup)

--1.Create index in geometry column:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_sc_48_lom_ar5_geom ON mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5 USING GIST("SP_GEOMETRY");
```

--2. Function:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker() RETURNS trigger AS $sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker$
        BEGIN
            -- INSERT
            IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    SELECT ST_Buffer("SP_GEOMETRY",5, 'quad_segs=8') FROM mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5;
    UPDATE mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5 
    SET "Location_ID" = poles_lom_ar5."Location_ID"
    FROM mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5
    WHERE  ST_Contains (mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY", mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY");
                RETURN NEW;
            -- UPDATE
            ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
    SELECT ST_Buffer("SP_GEOMETRY",5, 'quad_segs=8') FROM mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5;
    UPDATE mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5 
    SET "Location_ID" = poles_lom_ar5."Location_ID"
    FROM mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5
    WHERE  ST_Contains (mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY", mapinfo.public.poles_lom_ar5."SP_GEOMETRY");
                RETURN NEW;
            END IF;
        END;
    $sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

--3. Create trigger:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker ON mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5;
CREATE TRIGGER trg_sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5_tracker();
```

SQL applying without errors, but when I'm trying to save edits I'm receiving error:

> ODBC Error: ODBC RC=-1, ODBC SQLState=42601, DBMS RC=1,
>   DBMS Msg=ERROR: query has no destination for result data;
>   Error while executing the query. Operation cancelled.

Comment: tried to play with:
RETURN (mapinfo.public.sc_48_lom_ar5."Location_ID");

always same answer

Comment: Your `SELECT`s in the trigger function are not doing anything with the returned data - but more importantly: those selects are retrieving **all** rows from the table `poles_lom_ar5` - surely that's not what you want.

Comment: Probably need redo all at the morning, but goal was to make buffer for points which should contain points which I need to update with information from first points ( buffered).  So I made it like select.